# How do you interpret a categorical response coefficient in a regression analysis?

Tags: regression

I have a regression model with a continuous response variable called Variation and 3 Categorical predictors called Thickness(0.040 or 0.074), Sequence(1 or 2), and Speed(50 and 70). The lower values are the reference variables. I'm looking at the relationships between the predictors and the response. I have output from Minitab that I'm having trouble putting into words. I am confused if this is the right way to phrase this...but is there .000264 less variation than the thinner .040 material?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's relative to the omitted predictor. Isn't 0.040 the coefficient on "thickness"?